A question about the definition of a regular function on an affine algebraic set in Algebraic Geometry
I'm confused about this when accepting the definition of the regular funciton:
$\quad$When we talking about an affine algebraic set $V$ equipped with zariski topology, we may really stay at the purely topological category. But if we further consider the regular function on it, do we always potentially fix a positive integer n to get an $A^n$ and a specific way about how V contained in $A^n$ ?
$\quad$ In other words, assume there are two affine algebraic sets $X\subset A^n, Y \subset A^m$ equipped with zariski topology are homeomorphic by some maps. Is this correct: there always be a map to take them isomorphic under the sheaf of ring of regular functions ? Or would this situation happen: for some specific $X$ and $Y$, they really never be isomorphic under the sheaf of ring of regular funtions ?
I prefer that we awlays previously fix a number n and way how it included in $A^n$ when we talking about an affine variety $V$, an affine open subet of a variety or a similar question with ans for the scheme theory. Because I have heard that the modern geometry is about topological space and the functions on it although I don't know why it acts like this but in the differential geometry they exactly so did. And a trivial example is putting the real line $R$ in $R^2$ by two ways homeomorphically, one of them straight but another analytically weird implying pure topology might be too broad, so the functions on space may asked to be previously defined before we starting do geometry. 
$\quad$I need some evaluations about this idea, and if these words not too far from the facts, I might need an anti-example for zariski homeomorphic but non-isomorphic up to structure sheaf.
$\quad$Furtherly, I really want to know why modern geometry showing like this, and why affine algebraic sets chose regular function, how geometers confirm desired funcitons is exactly what they want to form a category with moderate compatibility not too strong and not too weak?

Hi, welcome to the site. I think there are too many different questions here, it's a hard question to answer. Consider focusing on something in particular: for example, are you really asking if two classical affine varieties can be homeomorphic but not isomorphic? The answer is yes, I am told that any two classical curves over the same field are (Zariski-)homeomorphic but not all curves are isomorphic

Thank you. Any proper closed subset is a finite set since K[x] is a p.i.d. , and any finite subset is closed, so any bijective map is a homeomorphism. I am a bit thoughtless before asking.
